# The jquery post from a view's form to its PHP controller is not posting

Tags: php, jquery, model-view-controller, post

What is to be the value of `$id` is determined by a php file, 'afile.php', which gets to the view using `include('view_file.php')`. I want the form in 'view_file.php' to post data back to 'afile.php' and use it to again determine the value of `$id`.

From the 'view_file.php':
Here is my jquery/javascript:

```
function vote() 
  {
    $.post('afile.php',{ poll:$('input:radio[name=poll]:checked').val(), id: $('input:hidden[name=id]').val()});
  };
```

Here is my form:

```
 <form name='poll' id='poll'>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='poll3' checked/>Yes
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='poll2'/>Done
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='poll1'/>No
    <INPUT TYPE='button'  value='submit' onClick="vote();" />
    <INPUT TYPE='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id; ?>'/>
</form>
```

From the 'afile.php':

```
if(isset($_POST['poll']))
{
   //code
}
else
   //code
include('view_file.php');
```

However, the post is never set, and I just cannot figure out why that is.

Any help/hints/suggestions appreciated.

EDIT:
I realized I can do this easily without incorporating jquery/javascript. 
Just use the HTML POST method:

```
<form name='poll' action='afile.php' method='POST'>
   <INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='poll3' checked/>Yes
   <INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='poll2'/>Done
   <INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='poll1'/>No
   <INPUT TYPE='submit'  value='submit' />
   <INPUT TYPE='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id; ?>'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `$('formSelector').serialize()` to get the post data from the form directly, without needing to get the values for each input. Checkboxes and Radios only send POST data if they are `:checked`.

Now, it doesn't matter what the form's name is, it isn't passed to $_POST, so your condition

```
if(isset($_POST['poll']))
```

Will always be false, since there is not **input** with the name of 'poll'. I generally add a name to the submit button if there are multiple forms submitted to the same page.

EDIT: When testing locally the following code worked flawlessly:

```
<?php

    $id = 1;
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        if (!empty($_POST['poll'])) {
            echo "POLL IS NOT EMPTY!! \n";
            var_dump($_POST);
            die();
        }
        else {
            echo "BOO! POLL IS EMPTY! \n";
            var_dump($_POST);
            die();
        }
    }


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="Rikudo Sennin" />

        <title>Untitled</title>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#poll').submit(function() {
                $this = $(this);
                $.post(
                    "form-get-test.php",
                    $this.serialize(),
                    function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                )

                return false;
            });
        })

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form name='poll' id='poll'>
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='poll3' checked/>Yes
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='poll2'/>Done
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='poll1'/>No
        <INPUT TYPE='button'  value='submit' onClick="vote();" />
        <INPUT TYPE='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id; ?>'/>

        <button type="submit" name="poll_submit">Send</button>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_Will always be false, since there is not input with the name of 'poll'._" But I do have an input with name 'poll'--all 3 radio buttons do: `<INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='poll3' checked/>Yes` And I already have one checked by default. And there is only one form.

Comment: My bad, didn't see the code correctly (clearly time for bed). You should try to use `if (!empty($_POST['poll'])) { }` instead. See if that works for you. Also, try to `var_dump($_POST)` and see what you get.

Comment: nope, doesn't work :(. I have noticed, though, that if i add a `function(output){}` to the post, the function does react (it still doesn't post, but it does, for example, let out an alert upon click).

Comment: @Marina see my updated answer, I tested locally and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code and it does work. However, I don't want alerts or another function to go with the `$.post`, and when I remove the `function(data) {alert(data);}` to be left with this part instead of it `$.post("test.php",$this.serialize())`, nothing happens when i click on 'send'.

Comment: @Marina Things do happen, you just can't see it, because you don't do anything with the returned data. So obviously, you won't see any changes done. If the form handler in PHP would have, for example, accessed that database, you'd see the results there. Also, check your console to see the POST request.